# Dimensionality of the target for DQN agent training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, q-learning, dqn

From what I understand, a DQN agent has as many outputs as there are actions (for each state). If we consider a scalar state with 4 actions, that would mean that the DQN would have a 4 dimensional output.

However, when it comes to the target value for training the agent, it is usually described as a scalar value = reward + discount*best_future_Q.

How could a scalar value be used to train a Neural Network having a vector output?

For example see image in
https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-q-learning-tutorial-mindqn-2a4c855abffc

[image: DQN]

Comment: can you provide the reference of the statement: "*..a DQN agent has as many outputs as there are actions (for each state)*" ?

Comment: See the image on https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/introduction-deep-q-learning-python/ for example. The DQN outputs match the number of actions.

Comment: I doubt the image reflects this, as it has a single node as output. My guess is that it simply shows the possible outputs (of that single node)

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right image? I have no way to paste the image here. Also look at many other blogs such as https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-q-learning-tutorial-mindqn-2a4c855abffc If you dont agree with this statement, then can you state how many outputs you think a DQN agent has?

Comment: I have edited your post to add the image, unfortunately it has to await approval

Comment: Actually you are right, the first image is confusing. I have used an image from the second link.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but again it is only a choice of architecture, one can model it in other ways as well

Answer (score 0):

I am of the opinion that this architecture is only one among others that can solve the same problem (for example one may have only 2 outputs one for the chosen action and one for the $Q$ value of that action, but I will not elaborate further on this).

What this architecture does is to output the whole function $Q(a)$, that is the $Q$ value as a function of action $a$. So each output node represents the $Q$ value for a certain action $a$ corresponding to that node (so node 1 corresponds to the $Q$ value for action $a_1$, node 2 to $Q$ value for action $a_2$ and so on..)

BUT this is NOT a vector output, in the usual sense of the term. This is a **functional output** that represents the whole function $Q(a)$ for each action $a$.

As far as the learning/decision rule is concerned things are as usual. Hope this is clear.